# How do I eliminate the padding around a wheel style DatePicker in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, datepicker

I am trying to eliminate the extra padding around the DatePicker without changing the font size. Using `scale` works to eliminate the padding but causes the picker to be overenlarged. The picker looks OK on small devices but on XL devices has lots of padding.

```
struct Onboarding: View {
    var body: some View {
        DatePicker("", selection: .constant(Date()), in: Date().addingTimeInterval(-120 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60)...Date(), displayedComponents: .date)
            .datePickerStyle(.wheel)
            .labelsHidden()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    }
}

struct Onboarding_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Onboarding()
    }
}
```

Below I attached an image of the correct behavior from the Health app and the observed behavior from SwiftUI (red box added for emphasis).

[image: Correct Behavior]
[image: Scrrenshot]